Compile error when calling operator<< on a custom type from a different namespace
I have a type in a nested namespace (abc::util) and its overloaded operator<<. However, trying to call it from the outer namespace (abc) causes a compile error:
<source>: In function 'void abc::func(std::ostringstream&, const Foo&)':
<source>:38:9: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const abc::Foo::MyType' {aka 'const abc::util::MyType'})
   37 |     oss << ';'
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~
      |         |
      |         std::basic_ostream<char>
   38 |         << foo.value;
      |         ^~ ~~~~~~~~~
      |                |
      |                const abc::Foo::MyType {aka const abc::util::MyType}

Here is the minimal example:
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <print>


namespace abc::util
{

struct MyType
{
    std::string value;
};

std::ostringstream&
operator<<( std::ostringstream& oss, const MyType& some_value )
{
    oss << some_value.value;
    return oss;
}

}

namespace abc
{

struct Foo
{
    using MyType = util::MyType;

    MyType value { "12345" };
};

void
func( std::ostringstream& oss, const Foo& foo )
{
    oss << ';'
        << foo.value; // does not compile
    
    // oss << ';';
    // oss << foo.value; compiles fine
}

}

int main( )
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    abc::func( oss, abc::Foo { } );
    std::println( "{}", oss.view( ) );
}

I don't exactly know why this compiles:
    oss << ';';
    oss << foo.value;

but this doesn't:
    oss << ';'
        << foo.value;

Any reasons?

The problem is that oss << ';' returns ostream&, not ostringstream&. That breaks the chaining.

The namespaces are irrelevant. - it says "operand types are 'std::basic_ostream'... ", and that doesn't match your prototype. See here for the same issue with only global names. Do you have any particular reason for only overlading for ostringstream?

If you change ostringstream to ostream in func and in operator<< it will work (oss in main can stay an ostringstream). It will also make them more general. Any reason not to do it ?

@wohlstad I don't need to make these types printable using things like std::cout or std::ofstream so I have only defined overloads for ostringstream and istringstream.

@digito_evo I understand, but making your code more general is a good thing in general. And in this case it's not more complicated to implement plus it will solve your current issue. So IMHO you should have a good reason to avoid it.

Added a complete answer, since comments here are ephemeral.

The problem:
oss << ';' returns ostream& and not ostringstream& and so you cannot chain the calls as you attempt with:
oss << ';' << foo.value;

Note that the namespaces are not relevant to this problem.
A solution:
A valid solution would be to change your operator<< and func to use std::ostream instead of std::ostringstream.
I.e.:
Change:
std::ostringstream& operator<<( std::ostringstream& oss, const MyType& some_value)

To:
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& oss, const MyType& some_value)

And change:
void func(std::ostringstream& oss, const Foo& foo)

To:
void func(std::ostream& oss, const Foo& foo)

Note that you can still use these functions from main() with std::ostringstream oss, since ostringstream is derived from ostream.
Therefore this solution will only make your code more general.
A final note:
You mentioned in the comments that you don't need to make these types printable using things like std::cout or std::ofstream, but I don't see why it is an argument against this solution:
Making your code more general is usually a positive thing.
The fact that you don't need it (at the moment or even ever) does not change this.
And in this specific case the more general implemenetation is very easy to achieve.
Of course there could be specific reasons to avoid generality (which is why I wrote "usually"), but you didn't specify any.

The main reason is that I don't want to allow the code to intentionally or unintentionally write these types to a file through ofstream.

You could add assert(dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(oss)); inside func. I admit it is not ideal and will catch the problem only at runtime, but just in case you have no better solution.

What does the dynamic cast do in an assert? Is it supposed to throw when down casting?

dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&> will return null if oss is not a ref to ostringstream (or derived from it) and then the assert will pop (because it is equivalent to false). You can try it by passing e.g. an std::ofstream. As I said I'm not too happy with this suggestion and a compile time solution (if you found one) would be better.

Actually it looks fine to me. An assert is disabled in release builds so I'm ok with this solution. Thanks.
